# Call function with dots arguments and default value in another function with dots arguments and default value

Tags: r

I want to call R function with dots arguments and default value in another function with dots arguments and default value. This is my code

```
f<- function(x, y, z = 3, ...){
  x*y*z
}
g <- function(w = 4, ...){
  w*f(x, y, z, ...)
}
```

It only works when I give value to `z`:

```
g(w = 2, x = 1, z = 1, y = 5)
[1] 10
```

However `g(w = 2, x = 1, y = 5)` gives error message.

Comment: use `w*f(...)`  and that will take into consideration all that you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Onyambu replied in the comments. But I want to put his answer here hoping that it can help someone.

```
f<- function(x, y, z = 3, ...){
  x*y*z
}
g <- function(w = 4, ...){
  w*f(...)
}
g(w = 2, x = 1, y = 5)
[1] 30
```